# Exception when trying to get data from SSL certificate

Tags: c++, c, exception, openssl

I am trying to decode a certificate my server is sending for each of the objects I enroll. I am trying to get the serial and the validity date for the objects. I have my certificate stored in a `std::string` called certStr and the code I have is:

```
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
ERR_load_crypto_strings();

BIO* input(BIO_new(BIO_s_mem()));
BIO_puts(input, certStr.c_str());

// Create an openssl certificate from the BIO
X509* cert(PEM_read_bio_X509(input, NULL, NULL, NULL));

// Create a BIO to hold info from the cert
BIO* output_bio(BIO_new(BIO_s_mem()));

ASN1_INTEGER* bs = X509_get_serialNumber(cert);
```

and I am getting an exception

```
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION reading address 0x0000000000000008
```

with that last `X509_get_serialNumber` function. Do you know what could I be doing wrong? I am pretty new to OpenSSL, so I may have done something stupid that I am not realizing. I am also following [this](http://www.zedwood.com/article/c-openssl-parse-x509-certificate-pem) and [this](https://gist.github.com/cseelye/adcd900768ff61f697e603fd41c67625) code snippets that supposedly do what I am trying to do.

Comment: What's the return value from BIO_puts?

Comment: @stark 1568, which is the size of the data written into the file I am assuming, right?

Comment: What's the return value from PEM_read_bio_X509?

Comment: @Armali it is returning null, I supose that is why is throwig the exception. But why could it be returning null?

Comment: What's the "input" value?

Comment: @Armali it is a valid pointer

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the problem. The server is passing me a PKCS7 certificate, not a PEM certificate, so first I will have to extract the cert from the PKCS7 and then parse the certificate